# inconsistent results from min-max theorem & Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let
$$
Ax=y, \quad ||y||=1
$$
where $A$ is an $n$ by $n$, symmetric PSD matrix,   $0\leq \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq  \dots \leq \lambda_n  $ are the eigenvalues.

**1. Min-max theorem**

Let $M=A^2$, so its $i$th eigenvalue is $ \lambda_i^2$. The min-max theorem

$$
 \lambda_1 ^2 \leq \frac{x^TM x}{x^Tx} \leq  \lambda_n^2 
$$
and
$$
x^TM x =\langle Ax, Ax \rangle = ||y||^2=1
$$
leads to
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda_n^2 } \leq||x||^2\leq\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2 }  \quad (1)
$$

**2. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality**

Diagonalize $A=Q\Lambda Q^T$, so $A^{-1}=Q\Lambda^{-1} Q^T$, where $\Lambda^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix containing $1/\lambda_i$.

Since $x=A^{-1}y$,

$$
||x||^2=y^T (A^{-1})^T  A^{-1} y= y^T  Q  (\Lambda^{-1})^2  Q^T y = |\langle \operatorname{diag}(\Lambda^{-1}),Q^Ty\rangle|^2
$$

let $z=Q^Ty$, we have
$$
||x||^2= \sum_i^n  \frac{ z_i^2}{\lambda_i^2} 
$$

since  $||Q^T y ||=||z||=1$, Cauchy-Schwarz inequality gives

$$
 ||x||^2 \leq ||\operatorname{diag}(\Lambda^{-1}) ||^2 ||z||^2 =||\operatorname{diag}(\Lambda^{-1})||^2= \sum_i^n    \frac{1}{\lambda_i^2} \quad (2)
$$

**3. problem**

The result (1) is not consistent with (2), what's wrong?  Especially, can $||x||^2$'s maximum value reach $$\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}$$ or $$\sum_i^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i^2} $$?

Comment: How is $\langle\Lambda^{-1},Q^Ty\rangle$ defined?  $\Lambda^{-1}$ is a matrix; $Q^Ty$ is a vector.

Comment: It should be $\langle \Lambda^{-1}Q^Ty,Q^Ty\rangle$

Comment: it is $|\langle \operatorname{diag}(\Lambda^{-1}), Q^Ty \rangle|^2$

Answer (score 1):

First of all: in the sequence of equations, I believe that you meant to say
$$
||x||^2=y^T (A^{-1})^T  A^{-1} y= y^T  Q  (\Lambda^{-1})^2  Q^T y = \langle\operatorname{diag}(\Lambda^{-1}),Q^Ty\rangle.
$$
This statement is not quite true.  Taking $z = Q^Ty$, we find that 
$$
z^T (\Lambda^{-1})^2 z = \frac 1{\lambda_1^2} z_1^2 + \cdots + \frac 1{\lambda_n^2}z_n^2.
$$
From here, we could apply [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure) in the $p=1,q=\infty$ case to find that $\|x\|^2 \leq \frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}$.

Second: there is no inconsistency.  As you established, we have $\frac{1}{\lambda_n^2 } \leq\|x\|^2\leq\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2 }$. This is consistent with the statement that $\|x\|^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n    \frac{1}{\lambda_i^2}$.

So your statement derived from the misapplication of the Cauchy Schwarz inequality is correct.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. Now I understand that there is no inconsistency. However, I am interested in whether $||x||^2$'s maximum value can reach $\frac{1}{\lambda_1^2}$ or $\sum_i^n \frac{1}{\lambda_i^2} $, given arbitrary $y$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "given arbitrary $y$". Are you asking about
$$
\max \|x\| \quad \text{s.t. } x \in \Bbb R^n, \ Ax = y
$$
for a fixed vector $y$, or about
$$
\max \|x\| \quad \text{s.t. } x,y \in \Bbb R^n, \ Ax = y?
$$

Comment: I think it is max$||x||$ s.t. $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $Ax=y$. since $x$ is uniquely determined by $y$ in the context.

Comment: If $x$ is uniquely determined, then $y$ is uniquely determined too

Comment: yes, you are right. But I mean to find the maximum $||x||$, regarding as $y$ as variable, and $x$ is computed from $Ax=y$.